# Spring Boot Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying use to postgresql but i have this error.Here's my application properties

```
server.port=8081
application.name= = Address Registration
application.version = 1.0.0

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/addressRegistration
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= 12345
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen during the context loading when spring registers the beans required to finalize the program execution. There can be few options to check.

1. The dependency for h2 database is missing in your pom.xml. Hence the jar was not downloaded in the classpath.
2. Autoconfiguration is messed up. You can try with `@EnableAutoConfiguration( exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})`
3. You might have some settings left with h2 database in your app.properties, however you don't want to use h2 database.